# Android: Keep TextInputEditText in view when typing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, mobile, android-softkeyboard

I'm attempting to create an activity with a couple of `TextInputEditText` elements. These are placed about half way down the page, causing them to be covered by the keyboard when it appears. As such, I'm trying to use `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` inside the `AppManifest.xml` to have the screen scroll to keep the text boxes in view when typing.

However, all attempts at this seem to be failing. Below is the layout hierarchy I'm using, followed up some examples of solutions I've already attempted to no avail.

*layout xml*

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/inputAText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/inputBText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

*AndroidManifest.xml snippet*

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

---

**Attempted Solutions**

1. Add `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the relevant `activity` in `AppManifest.xml` (I have also tried `adjustResize` and `adjustPan|adjustNothing` as according to other StackOverflow suggestions)
2. Place the `ConstraintLayout` inside a `ScrollView`
3. Add `android:isScrollContainer="false"` to said ScrollView
4. Recreate the layout file with only a `ConstraintLayout` and `TextInputEditText` constrained to the bottom of said layout
5. Change `TextInputEditText` to `EditText` and remove `TextInputLayout`
6. Changed `ConstraintLayout` to `RelativeLayout`

For what should be a fairly simple implementation I'm at a loss. Any further suggestions are appreciated. I'm happy to provide more code samples if necessary.

Comment: have you tried with out the scroll view?. have only constrain layout. In worst case try relative layout instead of constrain layout.... may or may not work

Comment: Alas, neither solution worked, thanks though!

Comment: Didn't get you. (My poor English ). Can i know what you are trying to say? Which one got worked?

Comment: Sorry, they both did not work.

Comment: Have you tried without  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" line in manifest. I think by default it will make the view up.  Are you using real device to test or emulator ?

Comment: I've tried removing `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` from the manifest, but unfortunately this didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using real device or emulator?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm testing on several real devices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183554/discussion-between-suresh-and-tom-barden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem! In my theme I declared `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`. For some reason, this breaks `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, and as such I removed it.

In order to keep the status bar transparent, I use `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>`.

Hopefully someone, someday finds this useful.